# "See figure below" for besides?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

In a textbook, to refer to a figure below the text you would say "See figure below." What about for figures beside the text?

Comment: Just say "See figure 10"- that way when things shift around, the wording doesn't need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to deal with this situation. As Jim points out in a comment below the question, one way to avoid the whole issue is to number the figures and refer to particular figures by number in their in-text references ("see figure XX," for example).

But sometimes the informality of the desired presentation makes figure numbering seem odd. This was evidently the case at the computer magazines where I worked: we never assigned figure numbers to figures, to avoid having the presentation seem unduly regimented, I suppose. In such situations you can say "see the figure above," see the figure below," "see the figure at left," or "see the figure at right," as appropriate.

As long as the figure in question is the only one above, below, at left, or at right of the in-text reference, the reader is in no doubt about which one the author means, so this approach is no burden on the reader. It is, however, a serious burden on the writer, designer, and editors, who must ensure that the figure remains in the specified relationship to the in-text reference as the article inches toward publication—and if the relationship changes, someone needs to be alert enough to notice the change and modify the in-text language accordingly.